# How to fetch image using URL API from localhohst?

Tags: cloudinary

I followed the document to prefix my image url with their URL API:

```
https://res.cloudinary.com/<my Cloudinary account's cloud name>/image/fetch/http://localhost:3000/img/example.jpg
```

It won't fetch.

I have added `localhost:3000` to Allowed fetch domains on the Settings security page already. Not working.

Then I tested it with my testing server with a domain. It works.

How to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using 'fetch' Cloudinary needs the domains to fetch from to be publicly accessible domains (for example - mydomain.com). As your localhost is only accessible in your own specific server/network and is invisible everywhere else, Cloudinary and everyone else can't see it but you.

Comment: ... but one could use localtunnel.me or ngrok to expose localhost to the world and cloudinary